# compute the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{1+x} \,dx$

Tags: integration, limits

I've tried using Taylor expansion but that didn't really work out. I'm really stuck and don't know where to begin. I even tried putting it on wolfram alpha but he couldn't solve it either.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^2(nx) = (1 - \cos(2nx))/2$.
For any integrable function $f$, by the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} f(x) \cos(2nx)\; dx = 0$$
So that leaves you with $$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+x} $$

Comment: $f(x) = 1/(1+x)$ is a continuous function, therefore integrable, on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$.  The (first) version in Wikipedia is for an integral on the real line, but you can just take the function to be $0$ outside the interval.

Comment: If you're going to be working with integrals involving trigonometric polynomials, it's definitely worthwhile to learn something about Fourier series.